Class constructor using reference tor Rcpp::NumericVector
this code (content of file src.cpp)
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
template<typename T>
class baseX{
private:
protected:
  std::string N_;
  std::vector<T> A_;
public:
  baseX(std::string const N):N_{N}{};
  baseX(std::vector<T> const &X):A_{X}{};
};

baseX<double> * base_constructor_1(Rcpp::NumericVector &A){
  std::vector<double> X;
  for(int i=0;i<A.length();++i){
    X.push_back(A(i));
  }
  return new baseX<double>(X);
}

RCPP_MODULE(baseEX){
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<baseX<double>>("baseX")
    .constructor<std::string>()
    .factory<Rcpp::NumericVector&>(base_constructor_1)
    ;
}
RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(baseX<double>);

when compiled using this R script
library(Rcpp)
system("rm -r BBB*")
Rcpp.package.skeleton("BBB",
                      cpp_files="src.cpp",
                      code_files="zzz.R",
                      force=TRUE,
                      example_code=FALSE)
system("R CMD build BBB")
system("R CMD INSTALL BBB")

,with content of file zzz.R being only loadModule("baseEX",TRUE), produces this error message:
In file included from /usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:135,
                 from /usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:69,
                 from src.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_Factory.h: In instantiation of ‘Class* Rcpp::Factory_1<Class, U0>::get_new(SEXPREC**, int) [with Class = base<double>; U0 = Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’:
/usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_Factory.h:51:18:   required from here
/usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_Factory.h:52:21: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&>::type’ {aka ‘Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’}
   52 |       return ptr_fun( bare_as<U0>(args[0]) ) ;
      |              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:200: src.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BBB’

The code compiles when base_constructor_1(Rcpp::NumericVector &A) and factory<Rcpp::NumericVector&> are change to base_constructor_1(Rcpp::NumericVector A) and factory<Rcpp::NumericVector> (i.e. when the argument to the factory method is provided by value, not by reference).
Further, even when successfully compiled the constructors get mixed up:
> library(BBB)
> x<-new(baseX,"bla")
> x<-new(baseX,numeric(5))
Error: Expecting a single string value: [type=double; extent=5].
>

Any idea how to get this to work?
Thanks
NB: OS Linux
R version: 4.3.3
Rcpp version: 1.0.12
C++ compiler: g++ 13.2.1

Hm, are you sure you can template on Rcpp types which are after all just wrapper around a SEXP which uses run-time resolution as a union type? Have you seen any supporting documentation suggesting it, or a working example?

The example runs if you replace the second constructor by a .method, i.e. you construct the object using the first constructor and then use a method to fill the vector. It appears as if the trouble occurs as soon as an Rcpp class is involved in the constructor.
